# What zip library works well with Ruby 1.9.2?

Tags: ruby, zip, ruby-1.9.2, rubyzip

I used the rubyzip gem in Ruby 1.8.7 before, but I heard rubyzip doesn't work well with ruby 1.9.2.

What zip libraries work well with Ruby 1.9.2?

Answer (score 5):

Have you actually tried using `rubyzip` with 1.9.2? Seems to work fine for me:

```
>> RUBY_VERSION 
#=> "1.9.2"
>> require 'zip/zip' 
#=> true
>> Zip::ZipFile.foreach(File.expand_path("~/Downloads/Archive.zip")) { |f| p f } 
#=> [bartxt, footxt]
bar.txt
foo.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I used `rubyzip` gem in Ruby 1.8.7 also. For Ruby 1.9.x you need to use version 0.9.5 or higher. Works without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I found [zip](http://rubygems.org/gems/zip) it says it's compatible with 1.9.1 I don't think it would have any issues in 1.9.2